# github access to ros_comm broken?

Tags: ros, ros-comm, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to chase down a problem running rostest on a dry stack under Groovy. But, when I go to https://github.com/ros/ros_comm, it says:

```
Sorry,
this tree took too long to generate.
```

Is it just me, or is there a serious github scaling problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55375/github-access-to-ros_comm-broken?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-16**:
Looks like it's just the groovy-devel branch. Maybe there's a symlink cycle? I'm not sure how git handles that.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-16**:
You're right about other branches working, Dan. But, I don't see any recent commits that look like symlink changes.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-16**:
I can confirm this. If you just need a look at the current source code: I could still fork ros_comm and in my fork groovy_devel shows just fine.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-16**:
I wonder if ros_comm recently exceeded some github display limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We contacted GitHub and they did something that "fixed" it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2